# change .emacs in linux

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I'm trying to change my .emacs file, which I think is placed in my Home directory as .emacs.d, however, I don't know how to add my directory to this file. I tried with vim, but it didn't work and my emacs does not support my commands. (if anyone is familiar with hol 4, I wanna use emacs as my hol 4 editor, but when I use M-h h, nothing happens.)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `.emacs` file is in `$HOME/.emacs` not `$HOME/.emacs.d/.emacs`